# Embed Iframe at my facebook fan page

Tags: html, facebook

How can I embed iframe at my facebook fan page?

I want to have this:
[image]

but I have this:
[image]

How I can do it right?
Here is my iframe page.
http://mobilepolice.ru/pages/default/facebookpage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed iframe or any custom content to your wall tab like your top photo shows.  You can only embed custom content on a separate tab like you are doing with photo #2.  You can make your custom iframe tab the default landing pages for users that are not fans of your page yet by going into the settings for your page.  People that are fans will always default to the wall tab though which again cannot have the custom content you desire.

Answer (score 0):

IT is possible by using this tab and setting it as default tab. http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=190322544333196&pages